# Django - NoReverseMatch. What am I overlooking?

Tags: python, django

My app name is 'canyonero'. I'm using Django 1.11 on Pypy 5.6.0.

The app is enabled in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'canyonero.apps.CanyoneroConfig',
    ...
]
```

There is a route to the app in my project-level urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^product/canyonero/', include('canyonero.urls', namespace='canyonero')),
    ...
]
```

There is a namespaced URL to be resolved in my app-level urls.py:

```
app_name = 'canyonero'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^events/(?P<pk>\d)/$', EventDetail.as_view(), name='event'),
    ...
]
```

And then this template tag gives me no end of grief:

```
{% extends 'common/content.html' %}
{% load static %}

<a href="{% url 'canyonero:event' pk=obj.event_id %}"></a>
```

The error I'm getting is:

`NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'event' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': 532742}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'product/canyonero/events/(?P<pk>\\d)/$']`

532742 is a valid primary key for a valid record (confirmed with `Event.objects.get()` in the shell), so it's not that.

Is there anything obvious that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\d` matches a single digit. You need to match multiple digits, so you need `\d+`:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EventDetail.as_view(), name='event'),
```

Comment: Figures it'd be something that trivial. I believe you're right; will mark as answered upon confirmation.